# detailed timing of operation in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, profiling

suppose i have some triggers on some table ON Insert.
How can i know what time it actually takes to insert and what time it takes to execute trigger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `explain (analyze, verbose)` for the statement that fires the trigger you will see the execution time of each trigger on the table.

So if you have a table `foo` with a trigger, and run something like this:

```
explain (analyze, verbose)
insert into foo (id) 
values (1);
```

You'll get an output similar to this:

```
Insert on foo (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=938.776..938.776 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: 1
Planning time: 0.040 ms
Trigger foo_trg: time=937.371 calls=1 <<<< here
Execution time: 938.802 ms
```

Note that `explain (analyze)` will in fact run that statement. So the new row will be inserted. You need to `rollback` if you don't want that.

Comment: @SMW: No, you will only see the execution time for each trigger